# How can I make windows not go beyond the edge of the desktop?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, desktop

In Ubuntu and other Linux distributions, windows stick to the edge of the screen instead of going directly beyond it, is it possible to make them do the same in Windows 7?

Comment: No it doesn't... I can have only 1 workspace/view and can make it go offscreen

Answer (score 1):

In Natty Narwhal alpha 3 (11.04 is due out in April), the Unity shell will do this. Just drag the window to the edge. Unless you want to run the alpha version, you will have to wait a few more weeks. I'll probably find myself acclimating to the Unity environment eventually... But I do miss the wobbly windows.